# How do I access the files in an ISO created with WinArchiver

Tags: iso

A friend from out of town recently gave me four .iso files on a USB stick. Several days later I tried to access the files using 7z; all I see in each ISO is a 0-byte file named "Please open the ISO file with WinArchiver.txt". The same thing happens when I mount one of the .iso files using loopback. Obviously winarchiver creates .iso files that are different from standard .iso files. Does anyone know how I can access these ISOs using ubuntu?

Comment: To clarify what I said in the original question, I have tried "sudo mount -o loop /tmp/isofile1.iso /mnt/iso1". All I see in the /mnt/iso1 directory is the 0-byte text file "Please open the ISO file with WinArchiver.txt"

Comment: Would you mind downloading a software "Furius ISO mount" and see if it gets mounted.

Comment: It's possible it's an UDF image instead of an ISO9660 image. Mount using `-t udf` to test.

Comment: @Raphael - Furius ISO mount gives me the same thing as the other methods.

Comment: @muru - adding "-t udf" causes the mount command to fail

Comment: I think the file got corrupted.

Comment: `-t udf` failed for me too. I think they have to be iso9660, because the mount works, and you can see the 0-byte file inside.
I've also got one of these files, and I'm starting to wonder if this is a virus, or perhaps a really crude marketing technique by the makers of WinArchiver. :-)

Comment: @Darren - It's not a virus; at least my files weren't, because I was able to extract the contents using my friend's WinArchiver. "crude marketing" is probably a charitable description of what I call hijacking an open standard and making it proprietary.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone find a real solution?